# Binomial probabilities in games when players can lie

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

An oracle can be asked a binary question.  If the real answer is *true*, the oracle says true with probability *tt* (and false with probability *tf=1-tt*).  If the real answer is *false*, the oracle says false with probability *ff* (and true with probability_ft=1-ff_).  So the oracle is defined as P(q) = { tt, ff}.

When the oracle is asked *the same question* *n* times and answers *true* *at least m times*, what is the probability that the real answer is *true*?

Comment: By and large, you're better off posting these sorts of Probability questions over at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ represent if the real answer is true ($R=T$) or not ($R=F$). Let $N$ ($<n$) be the number of times the oracle says true. The required quantity is $\text{P}(R=T|N\ge m)$. Use Bayes theorem:

$$\text{P}(R=T|N\ge m) = \frac{\text{P}(N\ge m|R=T)\text{P}(R=T)}{\text{P}(N \ge m)}$$

Assuming the oracle answers each question independently,

$$\left( N|R=T \right) \sim \text{Bin}(n, tt)$$

A similar expression for $N|R=F$ can be obtained, allowing the calculation of the probabilities involving $N$ in the question.

No information regarding $\text{P}(R=T)$ is given, so a prior probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ might be assumed.